# Haddock not obeying ignore-exports correctly

Tags: haskell, haddock

Take this example:

```
{-# OPTIONS_HADDOCK ignore-exports #-}
module HaddockTest (e1) where

-- * Exported

-- | This is exported.
e1 :: Int
e1 = 1

-- * Private

-- | This is not exported.
p1 :: Int
p1 = 1
```

Strangely, the doc-string for the non-exported declaration is ignored, even though we get the structure otherwise correctly:

[image: Haddock output shows e1 with doc, p1 without.]

Does anyone have a clue? For the record, invoking via `cabal haddock --internal` doesn't help, nor does `haddock --ignore-all-exports`.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in haddock-2.10. The doc string for `p1` is included by 2.9.2 (ghc-7.0.4) and 2.9.4 (ghc-7.2.2).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks for the tip. I couldn't be sure if that was the case, or if it was just me.

Comment: It could still be just we two. But bug is more likely.

Comment: @DanielFischer: would you like to submit your comment as the answer, so I might accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [bug in haddock-2.10](http://trac.haskell.org/haddock/ticket/196), reported in March and fixed soon after, but the haddock shipped with GHC-7.4.1 was affected. Presumably the haddock shipped with 7.4.2 includes the fix (haven't built 7.4.2 yet).